# External build can't find import

Tags: java, build-process, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on an Eclipse RCP project on Eclipse 3.6 that's broken up into 3 Java projects.

[image]

Starting from the bottom, `gov.bop.rabid.xxx.ui` is the RCP project.  The other two Java projects are included into the rabid RCP project.

I've added these two Java projects as dependencies to my rabid project.

[image]

[image]

When I build the RCP product inside of Eclipse, everything builds and runs.

When I use the Eclipse product export wizard, I get the following error message in the `logs.zip` file:

```
# 1/13/12 9:02:45 AM EST
# Eclipse Compiler for Java(TM) 0.B61, 3.7.0, Copyright IBM Corp 2000, 2010. All rights reserved.
----------
1. ERROR in C:\BOPEclipse3.7RaBId\gov.bop.rabid.xxx.ui\src\gov\bop\rabid\xxx\ui\video\RabidVideo.java (at line 3)
    import gov.bop.eclipse.logging.EclipseLogging;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import gov.bop.eclipse cannot be resolved
```

I know that it's some kind of dependency error, but I can't find where in my RCP project to put the dependency.

Edited to add:

Here's the first part of the Rabid product dependencies list:

[image]

The two other workspace plugins are included on the dependencies list.

Here's the first part of the Rabid product Eclipse run configuration plug-ins list:

[image]

To answer Tonny Madsen's questions (and I appreciate the interest):

- gov.bop.eclipse logging is an Eclipse plug-in from an existing JAR Archive.
- com.aware.photocomponent is an Eclipse plug-in from an existing JAR Archive.

Here's the package explorer again, with the directories open:

[image]

There are 0 errors and 0 warnings associated with this workspace.

Comment: You write "When I build the RCP _project_ inside of Eclipse..." and "When I use the Eclipse _product_ export wizard..." - do you mean _project_ and _product_? Can you launch the _product_ from inside Eclipse?

Comment: @Tonny Madsen:  Yes, I can launch the product from inside Eclipse.  I fixed the question.

Comment: Can you see if `gov.bop.eclipse.logging` is built properly? If yes, can you find the `EclipseLogging` inside? Are there any other compilation errors? I have seen similar problems, where the real problem was in the dependents...

Comment: @Tonny Madsen:  I've updated the question to answer your questions.  I appreciate your interest.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The shown information is from the IDE. Right? Have you checked if the compiled `gov.bop.eclipse.logging` plug-in is correct when you _export_ the product? I had a problem very similar to this a few weeks ago, where the problem turned up to be an incorrect change of `build.properties`. As I remember it, I had incorrectly added a `src...` line to it... It working in the IDE, but the _exported_  plug-in was almost empty... resulting in errors very similar to yours.

Comment: @Tonny Madsen:  Yes, the information in the question is from the IDE.  I just exported the logging plug-in from the source again and rebuilt the logging plug-in in the RCP project from the JAR.  I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: When you export the logging plug-in - and just that - does the _exported_ jar contain the correct classes?

Comment: @Tonny Madsen: Yes, the logging plug-in contains the correct classes.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure what is wrong here. Anyway to get a archive version of the logging plug-in?

Comment: have you tried to add plug-in 'camera' instead import packages? have you tried to automatic start this plug-ins on your .product file BEFORE `org.eclipse.core.runtime` (with a start lever bigger than `org.eclipse.core.runtime` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to build the Eclipse RCP package when I removed the gov.bop.eclipse.logging plug-in project, and added the gov.bop.eclipse.logging jar to the gov.bop.rabid.xxx.ui classpath.

The logging plug-in jar is now a part of the ui plug-in jar.  While this "works", if I want to update the logging plug-in jar, I have to update the ui plug-in jar.  This is not an elegant solution, merely an effective solution.

It appears that this is the only way you can include external Eclipse plug-ins in an Eclipse RCP package.  I wish someone would prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a compiler error, this implies that the OSGi resolver was happy with your dependency setup, otherwise you would have failed before compilation with an unresolved dependency.

I suspect this is related to having the .class file binaries in the project instead of source .java files.  Try setting the [`output..`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/reference/pde_feature_generating_build.htm) property in `gov.bop.eclipse.logging/build.properties` to be the path to the folder containing packages with the .class files (relative to the project root).

If those are Plug-in Projects, you can double check the classpath that will be used during product export by right clicking on the gov.bop.rabid.xxx.ui/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file and selecting PDE Tools -> Create Ant Build File.  This will generate a build.xml file, you can inspect the "@dot" target to see the classpath being used.

Some other causes of this kind of problem (which I don't really thing are the case here) are:

- Having an incorrect `Bundle-ClassPath` entry in the manifest.  If not specified, the default value is '.', which means the .class files are in the root of the binary bundle.
- Having nested jars in your bundle, with one jar depending on the other, but not defining the order in which these jars are compiled (`jars.compile.order`).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I did find some problems with the build properties of the logging plug-in.  Unfortunately, fixing the build properties didn't fix the problem.  I did create the build.xml file and see where the Eclipse compiler was failing.  Unfortunately, manually manipulating the build.xml file just caused the steps after the dot step to be skipped.